# Creating a UIImage from two smaller UIImages

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, image-manipulation

I have two instances of `UIImage`. How can I create a third `UIImage` that's just the two original images stitched together? I'd like the first image on top and the second image on the bottom such that the top image's bottom edge is flush with the bottom image's top edge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something like this should work (I havent tested it though)

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithTopImage:(UIImage *)topImage bottomImage:(UIImage *)bottomImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(topImage.size.width, topImage.size.height + bottomImage.size.height);
    [topImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, topImage.size.width, topImage.size.height)];
    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, topImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height)];
    UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return combinedImage;
}
```

Comment: I think the CGSizeMake in the first line is missing a parenthesis.

Comment: Also, the bottomImage drawInRect call should probably start from a y-coordinate of topImage.size.height instead of its width.